# Why use realpath()?

Tags: php

PHP's `realpath()` is well described in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php), I'd just like to understand in which scenarios it is useful. Because it seems that my code works well enough with paths like `../../path` so I'm not really sure where `realpath()` is useful or even necessary.

Comment: Just out of my experience there are some servers (Microsoft)  where relative paths are turned off or you can't even turn it on! So there it would be useful

Comment: Symlinks are resolved by realpath() - that can be very useful for your code to know exactly where it is rather than via the symlinks

Comment: What happens if you move pieces of your code around, like change the depth of directories and such? That's quite common for code that's proof of concept and is not yet production-ready (because devs are testing things out). Would your code, in such a case, still work with relative paths?

Comment: realpath helps in two cases. First, it helps clean up messy paths. Second, it resolves symbolic links. Therefore, it helps you check to see the real path that a user is requesting. If I make a symbolic link in my folder to /etc, for example, and then try to use it, realpath would resolve that to /etc/...whatever I tried to do. You'd have an easier time identifying my attempt to subvert your path restrictions.

Comment: Initally PHP defined the function `fakepath()`, but it gave unreliable and unpredictable results.  So `realpath()` was added later as a correction.   ;-)

Comment: So is realpath() mostly useful for us, humans, when debugging things etc. while functions that accept path on their input don't really care whether they get ../../path or the realpaht()'d version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience I found `realpath()` useful for

#### 1. Clarity

when displaying/logging/storing a full path instead of a relative one is more desiderable.

#### 2. Safety

to ensure that a given file path is **below** (in the filesystem hierarchy) a "base" path, before doing something with that file (serving, editing, etc...)

Example:

```
$full_path = realpath( $relative_path );

if( $full_path !== false && strpos( $full_path, "/var/www/whatever/" ) === 0 )
{
    //...
}
```

---

A couple of things worth mentioning:

`realpath()` resolves symlinks.

`realpath()` returns `FALSE` if the file or directory doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

**THE BAD NEWS IS**

When you use a "dot-dot-slash" for your path you're in a warning state to be **attacked** using [Path Traversal](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal), This attack aims to access files and directories that are stored outside the web root folder. By manipulating variable that reference files with **"dot-dot-slash" (../)** sequences and it's variations, it may be possible to access arbitrary files and directories stored on file system, including application source code, configuration and critical system files, limited by system operational access control. The attacker uses "../" sequences to move up to root directory, thus permitting navigation through the file system.

This attack can be executed with an external **malicious code injected** on the path, like the **[Resource Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Resource_Injection)** attack. To perform this attack it’s not necessary to use a specific tool; attackers typically use a spider/crawler to detect all URLs available.

This attack is also known as "dot-dot-slash", "directory traversal", "directory climbing" and "backtracking".

you can check this over ..

**AND, THE GOOD NEWS IS....**

realpath() will let you convert any path that may contain relative information into an absolute path. You can then ensure that path is under a certain subdirectory that you want to allow access to.

For absolute path such as an URL's your subdomain and protocol can be controlled. People that enter through an obscure subdomain will be funneled into the proper subdomain. You can hop back and forth between secure and non-secure as appropriate. And, using it can be configurable, developers love things to be absolute.

You can design neat algorithms when using absolute URLs. URLs can be made configurable so that an URL can be updated site-wide with a single change in a single configuration file.

But if you look at this :

```
<a href=“index.php?q=”>index.php?q=</a>
<link src=“../.././../css/default.css” />
```

Are you not confuse of that ?

1. **CONFUSING**, How many dots is that? how many folders is that? Where is
   the file? Why isn't it working?
2. **MAINTENANCE**, If a file is accidentally moved resources quit loading,
   links send the user to the wrong pages, form data might be sent to
   the incorrect page. If a file NEEDS to be moved all the resources
   that are going to quit loading and all the links that are going to
   be incorrect need to be updated.
3. **IT'S DOES NOT SCALE**, when webpages become more complex and views
   start getting reused across multiple pages the relative links will
   be relative to the file that they were included into. If you have a
   navigation snippet of HTML that is going to be on every page then
   relative will be relative to a lot of different places. The first
   thing people realize when they start creating a template is that
   they need a way to manage the URLs.
4. **COMPUTED** - They are implemented by your browser (hopefully according
   to RFC). See chapter 5 in **[RFC3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)**.
5. **OOPS!!!** - Errors or typos can result in spider traps.

Sorry for my bad english... :)